# Select last inserted row for specific column id

Tags: mysql

I have table t1.

```
id    name     surname  last_updated

1       ABC      XYZ       2014-05-26 14:35:14

2       ABC      XYZ       2014-05-26 15:35:14  

3      LMN      SDF       2014-05-25 14:35:14

4      PQR      DFG       2014-05-24 14:35:14
```

I want record of row where name = ABC, but last_updated time= last inserted for ABC ..

Thanx in advance...

Prashant.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from t1 where name = 'ABC' order by last_updated desc limit 1
```

This will gives you the result in desc order and only the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE name='ABC'
ORDER BY last_updated DESC
LIMIT 1
```

**Explanation:**

Here the records are fetched in descending order of last_updated field whose name='ABC'. And the first records is selected.

**OR**

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName
WHERE name='ABC'
AND last_updated=(SELECT MAX(last_updated) as recentDate 
                  FROM TableName 
                  WHERE name='ABC')
```

Answer (score 0):

`select id from t1 where name= "name" order by last_updated desc limit 1`